# dynamic path in image src vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

There are many questions already asked on how binding image `src` is not working, and I've gone through them, which mentions to import the image using `require`. However, my question is a bit different: I am changing the image `src` based on the current `locale` the user has selected. I tried binding just a string in `src` based on `currentLocale`, but the image is not loading. I also tried `require` in the binding.

*File structure for assets:*

```
+ en
`-- download.jpeg
|
+ fr
`-- download.jpeg
```

*My component:*

```
<template>
  <div>
    <img :src="'../assets/en/' + this.currentLocale + '/download.jpeg'">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
//import { imageSrc } from "@/assets/en/download.jpeg";
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  data() {
    return {
      currentLocale: "en"
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-ek8iz)

Answer (score 2):

Your `src` binding has a bug in the path (`en` is hard-coded):

```html
<img :src="'../assets/en/' + this.currentLocale + '/download.jpeg'">
                      ^^^
```

But also it should use the `require` keyword on that path:

```html
<img :src="require('../assets/' + this.currentLocale + '/download.jpeg')">
```

A couple optimizations:

- `this` is unnecessary in the component's template, so you could just use `currentLocale` instead of `this.currentLocale`
- Vue CLI projects provide a path alias for the `src` directory (i.e., `@`), so you could use `@/assets` instead of `../assets`

*Result:*

```html
<img :src="require('@/assets/' + currentLocale + '/download.jpeg')">
```

---

*Codesandbox seems to exhibit [a bug](https://github.com/codesandbox/codesandbox-client/issues/1546) when `require`-ing image assets, so the code above won't work there. Try it locally in a Vue-CLI generated project.*